# Elasticsearch Searchguard configuration for Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, search-guard

I try to connect to Elasticsearch with Searchguard from Spring Boot app.

I create a bean for TransportClient.
It looks like that:

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
    .put(SSLConfigConstants.SEARCHGUARD_SSL_TRANSPORT_KEYSTORE_TYPE, "PKCS12")
    .put(SSLConfigConstants.SEARCHGUARD_SSL_TRANSPORT_KEYSTORE_FILEPATH, keyStore)
    .put(SSLConfigConstants.SEARCHGUARD_SSL_TRANSPORT_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, keyPassword)
    .put(SSLConfigConstants.SEARCHGUARD_SSL_TRANSPORT_TRUSTSTORE_FILEPATH, trustStore)
    .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
    .build();

TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings, SearchGuardPlugin.class);

TransportAddress[] addresses = clusterNodes.stream()
    .map(node -> {
         String[] url = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(node).split(":");
         return new TransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress(url[0], Integer.parseInt(url[1])));
    }).toArray(TransportAddress[]::new);

client.addTransportAddresses(addresses);
```

I have my repository extended ElasticsearchRepository.

But I receive a strange exception when my app starts:

> ERROR com.floragunn.searchguard.ssl.transport.SearchGuardSSLNettyTransport - SSL Problem error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE

What can be a reason? What part of code should I check?

I have another app which uses ElasticsearchTemplate directly (only SearchQuery). And there I don't have any problems.

Elasticsearch version: 6.4.3

Comment: Where do the keyStore and trustStore come from? How did you generate them?

Comment: They are generated not by me. But they work well in another project.

Comment: What problem can be with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, when I set `searchguard.ssl.transport.enable_openssl_if_available` to false:

```
...
.put(SSLConfigConstants.SEARCHGUARD_SSL_TRANSPORT_ENABLE_OPENSSL, false)
...
```